# parent and child same variable name,inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

if i have a class Fish

```
public class Fish {
int numberOfFins;
int age;
public Fish(int age){
    this.age=age;

}}
```

and class Shark that extends the Fish class

```
public class Shark extends Fish{
private int age;

public Shark(int age) {
    super(age);
    this.age=age;
}}
```

what age variable is accessed trough keyword this - is it of parent or from child class?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: As you appear to be starting out in Java, FWIW I **strongly** recommend using any of the several typical ways of indenting and brace placement, **not** the indentation and brace placement above. I've used one of the standard ones in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Which `age` you access depends on the **type** of the thing you use to access it. `this` always has the **type** of the class the method or constructor belongs to — that is, in `Fish`'s methods/constructors, `this` is of type `Fish`. In `Shark'`s methods/constructors, `this` is of type `Shark`. (There's only **one** object, which combines the features of `Fish` and `Shark` [yes, it really has two separate fields with the same name]; what we're talking about is the type of the reference to it.)

(Note that this is **different** for instance variables (like `age`; aka "fields") than it is for instance methods. In Java, methods are polymorphic, instance variables are not.)

So within `Fish` code, `this.age` is `Fish`'s `age`. Within `Shark` code, `this.age` is `Shark`'s `age`.

E.g.:

```
public class Fish {
    int numberOfFins;
    int age;
    public Fish(int age) {
        this.age=age;         // Sets Fish#age
    }
}

public class Shark extends Fish {
    private int age;

    public Shark(int age) {
        super(age);
        this.age=age;         // Sets Shark#age
    }
}
```

This doesn't only apply to `this`, it applies to variables as well. Look at `main` below (and notice that I set the two `age`s to different values; `Shark`'s `age` is twice `Fish`'s `age`):

```
class Fish {
    int numberOfFins;
    int age;
    public Fish(int age) {
        this.age = age;         // Sets Fish#age
    }
}

public class Shark extends Fish {
    private int age;

    public Shark(int age) {
        super(age);
        this.age = age * 2;     // Sets Shark#age
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shark s = new Shark(10);
        Fish f = s;
        System.out.println(f.age); // 10
        System.out.println(s.age); // 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

age will be inhereted from Fish but since you are decalring another variable with name "age" the inhereted variable will be hidden so what you will be having in your current object which is referenced by this is the variable declared in Shark

Answer (score -1):

[`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to
>   the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called.

```
public Fish(int age){
    this.age=age; / the one is Fish
}
```

Similarly in the other class, you have a member with the same name, which would be referenced in its c'tor :

```
public Shark(int age) {
    super(age);
    this.age=age; // the one in class Shark
}
```